# .I got this kind of error using flash messages in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session, header

here is the error:

> Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by
> "/var/www/project/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/AbstractDumper.php"
> at line 176.

I leave here my template and my controller:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        
         
        $post = new Post();
        
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);

        
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            //entity manager
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($post);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Article Created');

            // $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add();
            
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post.index'));
        }
}
```

here the template:

```
{% for message in app.flashes('success') %}
    <div class="alert alert-success" >
      {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I try to get what this code has to do with headers or what i can change here but i need help.
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the Symfony framework?  If so, which framework version? Typically these sorts of things happen when developers have things like 'new Session()' or $_SESSION in their code instead of letting the framework handle stuff.

Comment: Yeah , Symfony v5.2.99 , for the moment i did not set up no Session.

Comment: try to clear all sessions https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#flash-messages
also, try to open your project with private browser window (incognito) an see if the error exists or not

Comment: I ran a quick test and flashes work as expected in 5.2. You have something else going on.  Maybe setup a new project with a single controller action with just a single flash message.

Comment: The error you are seeing is typical of body content being sent to the browser before you set the header/flash. Sometimes this is because of white space at the end of a file. Other times it's because you need to set the header sooner.

Comment: I tried again i got the same error i am pretty sure i am not typing my for message in the right place , where do you guys use to set up this for?

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem I had :

```
public function showTitles(PostRepository $postRepository)
    {
        $posts = $postRepository->findAll();
        dump($posts);
        return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', [
            'posts' => $posts
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/create",name = "create")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function renderToForm(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $form->getErrors();
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($post);
            $em->flush();
            $estatus="post creado";
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add("estatus",$estatus);

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post.index'));

        }
        return $this->render('post/form.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

The problem was the line where i dump($post) , I commented that one and solved ,I hope this answer can help to someone else